# Python unexpected EOF in for loop [repl.it]

Tags: python

> **Note: This question is about a problem with repl.it, not a general problem.**
>
> ---
>
> Note: You might consider this as a duplicate, but in fact it isn't.
>   These do not suit my problem:
>
> - [Python unexpected EOF while parsing : syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401722)
> - [Python unexpected EOF while parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074225)
> - [Unexpected EOF while parsing in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32387372)
> - [Python unexpected EOF while parsing (python2.7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33295627)
>
> *(Taken from alerady answered questions list, duplicates excluded for compactness)*

I've got a problem with for loops in Python (repl.it [Python 2](//repl.it/languages/Python) and [Python 3](//repl.it/languages/Python3) interpreters) in that one-line for loops without a trailing newline raise `SyntaxError`.

```
for i in (1,2,3,4,): print i+i+i
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1
    for i in (1,2,3,4,): print i+i+i
                                   ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

```
for i in (1,2,3,4,): print i+i+i
# Trailing newline
```

```
3
6
9
12
```

Another question: How to display a trailing newline , trailing space or unprintable character in SE (without using <pre>)?

Comment: Could you provide some more details about your system? I'm on a Mac, Python 2.7.10 and I can't reproduce this issue. I've tried writing this to a file and just using the interpreter, but both run just fine.

Comment: Which OS are you using? with Ubuntu and Python2.7 or 3.5 the described problem doesn't exist.

Comment: @Arc676 I've said I'm using it on repl.it so you could give it a try there (Updated recently to Python 2.7.10 'cause of my feedback).

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this problem neither in Fedora nor in Windows.

Comment: @Ashafix On repl.it it exists.

Comment: @niyasc As I've replied to others, I'm using repl.it, so you could give it a try there.

Comment: Maybe repl has a bug?

Comment: @Arc676 Maybe yes, maybe no. If I get an answer I will feedback again.

Comment: That might be some issue with `repl`. Right now I don't have access to it.

Comment: @niyasc What is `repl`? (Note: don't use backticks when referencing an interpreter) Also, are you on work?

Comment: Seems to be repl specific. When using https://repl.it/languages/python3 the error is reproduced, one liner via the command line works or entering the function in python3 on Ubuntu works as well.

Comment: @Ashafix `for i in (1,2,3,4,): print(i+i+i)` reproduces the error on me. (REPL)

Comment: @Ashafix The header line 2 `[GCC 4.8.2] on linux` tells me it is compiled with GCC on a Linux OS, written in C/C++.

Comment: There error lies in the line before your for-loop. Possibly a missing `)`.

Comment: @Daniel It is a tuple, it can end with a `,`. That is not an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be a Python problem.

I tried your exact script without a newline on python 2.7 on OS X. It runs successfully. I also tried it on Python 3.5, after adding parens around the argument to `print`. Still no error.

Looks like a bug specific to `repl.it`.